# Infinite sums involving factorials

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

My question is

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{n!}= 2e$$

and $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{n!}= 2e$$

But each term in the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{n!}$$

except the first one is greater than each term in

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{n!}$$

So why isn't that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{n!} > \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{n!}$$

Comment: So it's been a while since I've used power series so I could be wrong, but I've never seen $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{n!}= 2e$. Are you sure that's correct?

Comment: Instead $\gt$ you get $\ge$ for an infinite series. And for this particular series, you get exactly the equality $=$.

Comment: In addition to SeraPhim's comment: the first $e = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} {1 \over n!}$, so you'rv dropped the term for $n = 0$ in your first identity.

Comment: In the first one, the index should begin at $0$  with $0!=1$

Comment: Anyways I understood why and yes

Comment: @SerapPhim: the second identity comes from differentiating the power series for $e^x$ term-by-term and using ${d e^x \over dx} = e^x$.

Comment: @SeraPhim: $n^2=n(n-1)+n$ and therefore $\frac{n^2}{n!}=\frac{1}{(n-2)!}+\frac{1}{(n-1)!}.$ You can use this fact to derive the said infinite sum.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please do note the comments noting that your first summation should start at zero. Anyway, you've answered your own question: it so happens that the fact that the first series has a larger first term makes up for the fact that every term in the second series except the first is larger than the respective term in the first series.

This fact should not be too difficult to swallow because the first few terms of both series are the ones that dominate the series, so you can imagine that the infinitely many terms that the second series is larger in each make minute contributions to even out the disparity due to the larger first few terms in the first series.